# Django call_command no-initial-data option

Tags: django, flush, manage.py

In Django, I would like to do this the `call_command` equivalent to

```
manage.py flush --no-initial-data
```

Something like

```
call_command('flush', interactive = False, initial_data = False)
```

but `initial_data` and `no_initial_data` are not the correct keyword (they do nothing).

Sorry for the trivial question, but I can't find any documentation for these options.

Comment: [`--no-initial-data`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/django-admin/#no-initial-data) is new in django 1.5. are you definitely using that?

Comment: Positive: 1.5.0.rc.1. But it doesn't prevent any initual data, it just does a normal flush. I'm expecting it to give a completely empty database, but reading the link, that may not be the intended use? All it does it skip the `initial_data` fixture? I want an empty database to import things into.

Comment: 1) This feature was deprecated in Django 1.9
2) It is really not safe to use initial_data because it silently overwrites your current state in db

Comment: @pymen Good to know it's deprecated, thanks. I don't see the danger of using initial_data though if you're flushing the database anyway.

Comment: @Mark the risks are when you do not want to flush: when you run "manage.py migrate" on your staging/prod and forgot to use "manage.py migrate --no-initial-data" - and if some records in real DB were changed since state from "initial_data"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

looking at the [source](https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/core/management/commands/flush.py#L20), it seems the `no-initial-data` option is stored in an option variable called `load_initial_data`

so i think you need

```
call_command('flush', interactive=False, load_initial_data=False)
```